# java -jar *.jar throw "Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21"

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This appears to be a bug in Spring Boot 3.2.0-RC1. I found it in the Spring Boot GitHub issues: [38050](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38050).

Thank you for everyone's help.

I am using Spring Boot 3.2.0-RC1 and have set 'spring.threads.virtual.enabled=true.' It runs fine in IntelliJ IDEA, but when I use 'mvn package' and then execute 'java -jar *.jar,' I get an exception: 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21.'

`java -version`

```
openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21+35 (build 21+35-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21+35 (build 21+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

`mvn -version`

```
Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.0/libexec
Java version: 21, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Users/majian/.sdkman/candidates/java/21-tem
Default locale: zh_CN_#Hans, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.0", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

error stack:

```
2023-10-26T10:22:05.731+08:00 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'applicationTaskExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutorConfigurations$TaskExecutorConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'applicationTaskExecutorVirtualThreads' threw exception with message: Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:545) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1174) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:748) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:450) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at com.jkzl.xiaowei.XiaoweiWebApplication.main(XiaoweiWebApplication.java:16) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[xiaowei-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[xiaowei-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:54) ~[xiaowei-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'applicationTaskExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutorConfigurations$TaskExecutorConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'applicationTaskExecutorVirtualThreads' threw exception with message: Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1441) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'applicationTaskExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutorConfigurations$TaskExecutorConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'applicationTaskExecutorVirtualThreads' threw exception with message: Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jpa/JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactoryBootstrapExecutorCustomizer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'applicationTaskExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutorConfigurations$TaskExecutorConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'applicationTaskExecutorVirtualThreads' threw exception with message: Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:545) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1468) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1390) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.resolveStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2196) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2190) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactoryBuilder(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:123) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicationTaskExecutor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutorConfigurations$TaskExecutorConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'applicationTaskExecutorVirtualThreads' threw exception with message: Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1651) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeanMap(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1573) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1512) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1390) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'applicationTaskExecutorVirtualThreads' threw exception with message: Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Virtual threads not supported on JDK <21
    at org.springframework.core.task.VirtualThreadDelegate.<init>(VirtualThreadDelegate.java:32) ~[spring-core-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.setVirtualThreads(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java:125) ~[spring-core-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.PropertyMapper$Source.to(PropertyMapper.java:294) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutorBuilder.configure(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutorBuilder.java:202) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutorBuilder.build(SimpleAsyncTaskExecutorBuilder.java:176) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutorConfigurations$TaskExecutorConfiguration.applicationTaskExecutorVirtualThreads(TaskExecutorConfigurations.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

Hope it works fine.

Comment: I suspect the terminal session is using a different JDK than IntelliJ. In the terminal session that is unable to run `java -jar *jar`, can you try `java -version`?

Comment: java -version output
'openjdk version "21" 2023-09-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21+35 (build 21+35-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21+35 (build 21+35-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)'

I use SpringBoot 3.2.0-M3 problem disappears

Comment: What is the complete stack trace of the `UnsupportedOperationException`?

Comment: You should try `mvn -version` to make sure mvn uses the JDK you think you are using.

Comment: `mvn -version` output
'Apache Maven 3.9.0 (9b58d2bad23a66be161c4664ef21ce219c2c8584)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.9.0/libexec
Java version: 21, vendor: Eclipse Adoptium, runtime: /Users/majian/.sdkman/candidates/java/21-tem
Default locale: zh_CN_#Hans, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "14.0", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"'